# Open a url in full screen mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullscreen

I am trying to open a URl in full screen on click of a button, am using the following code. The window does open full screen but then on the URL reload just goes back to the orignal screen size,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function toggleFullScreen() 
{
    if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) || (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) 
    {
        if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {  
          document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();  
        } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {  
            document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();  
        } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {  
            document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);  
        }  
    } 
    else 
    {  
        if (document.cancelFullScreen) {  
            document.cancelFullScreen();  
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {  
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();  
        } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {  
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();  
        }    
    }  
    window.location.href = "http://google.com/";    
}



</script>

<input type="button" value="click to toggle fullscreen" onclick="toggleFullScreen();">
```

I have even tried open page from the same domain, even that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I recommend using "screenfull" to avoid the boilerplate JavaScript you have: https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/

It will expose itself on the `window` object so it is as easy as this:

```
if (screenfull.enabled) {
    screenfull.request();
}
```

Second, As far as I know, you can't fix this. The browser requests permission from the user to open *specifically that page* in full screen and as you've said, that does work.

**When you use `window.location` you "navigate away" from that page and the full screen permission attached to it.**

Comment: i think it is deprecated now,

Answer (score 0):

From the console log:

> requestFullscreen() is deprecated on insecure origins, and support will be removed in the future. You should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.
>   (index):1 Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

---

From the above URL:

**Testing a Deprecated Powerful Feature**

After a feature has been deprecated, if you are a developer that needs to keep testing a feature on a server that does not have a valid certificate, you have two options:

- localhost is treated as a secure origin over HTTP, so if you're able to run your server from localhost, you should be able to test the feature on that server.
- You can run chrome with the --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="example.com" flag (replacing "example.com" with the origin you actually want to test), which will treat that origin as secure for this session. Note that you also need to include the --user-data-dir=/test/only/profile/dir to create a fresh testing profile for the flag to work.

---

**Bottom line**

It works only on secure servers, such as HTTPS. And to keep it open, the new URL must have the proper X-Frame-Options set.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an iframe containing the URL and use requestFullscreen on it :)